# Execute Variable Generated by Python Function in Pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have developped a generic python function that generates a variable that I want to execute in spark in order to get the needed Dataframe, details below (let's say i'm using pyspark shell directly):

```
#This is pyspark shell in cloudera platform

#Python Function
def generic_func(PARAMETERS):
 #Some operations
 return String_VARIABLE_To_Be_Executed

#Calling the function
df = generic_func(PARAMETERS)
exec(df)
```

But it seems that spark is still reading it as string variable, for the fact that when I execute the below code I get an error:

```
df.show()
```

I get the error below:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'show'
```

Just to give you somme context, by launching:

```
df
```

The variable generates something like:

```
"accountDF.alias('L1').join(account.alias('L2'), f.col('L1.MEMBERNAME') == f.col('L2.PARENT_NAME'), how='left')"
```

The output of the variable is more complexe than that, this is just to tell you that the variable has some spark functions that needs to be executed.

```
type(df)
<type 'str'>
```

Our perspective is to execute this variable like if we are executing any pyspark dataframe function. In other word, we would like to turn this string variable into an axecutable pyspark variable.

Can you please help!

Comment: can you please attach your exact code for the generic function. I suspect the return value is string type, you can confirm and update it by type(df)

Comment: Yes it is a string as I have specified above, please check the updates! Is there any way to convert this string to an executable spark variable?

Comment: @SudipM did I get your question right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options can be used either **exec(df)** or **eval(df)** to get the output result/dataframe, as shown below:

```
df = generic_func(PARAMETERS)
result = eval(df)
result.show()
```